# File rename no longer working

Tags: php, laravel

I have an update controller function in a laravel resource controller thats pretty basic. Updates the title, body etc. in the DB as normal (no issues with data updates).

The issue is with images. My image directory for each project follows a slug like naming convention based on the title of the project. I built the update function so that the directory and images would be renamed if the title was changed. This was working fine as soon as I built it, but it's suddenly stopped. The directory renames, but the files do not. Here is the relevant snippet from the controller:

```
    $count = 0;
    $slug = Input::get('title');
    $prefix = Str::slug($slug);
    $oldPrefix = $project->imagesprefix;
    $path = public_path().'/img/projects/';
    $directory = $path . $prefix;

    rename($path.$oldPrefix, $directory);

    //dumped directory here and it's definitely set
    $files = preg_grep('~\.(jpg)$~', scandir($directory));

    //dumped $files here and the array is definitely set
    foreach($files as $file){
        rename($directory.'/'.$file, $directory.'/'.$prefix.'-'.$count.'.jpg');
        ++$count;
    }
    rename($directory.'/thumbnails/'.$oldprefix.'-thumb.jpg', $directory.'/thumbnails/'.prefix.'-thumb.jpg');
```

All of this was working fine when tested this afternoon. Now it updates the DB, renames the directory folder but fails to rename the files. I've dumped the both $files and $directory before the loop and they are both set.

Comment: did you check file permissions ? `ls -l`

Comment: That was it. I could have sat in front of that for a year and not even thought of it. Do you have to reset permissions after every directory renaming? I had set a 0777 on creation which I thought would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If file rename fails then this is quite often related to permissions.

Comment: The problem is with the dynamically created directory for the image uploads. I set it to 777 when creating, but it does not apply these permissions which is odd. It keeps applying read only. I just need to dig a little deeper into Laravels `File::makeDirectory()` method to see how it works under the hood. I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary, just passing the path and permission to the method which was working fine yesterday morning.